# Removing rows from all columns based on values of one column

Tags: matlab

i have a data of 732x26 and one of the column contains unwanted values, i used

```
logicalIndex = FOMassFlow > MeanFOMassFlow;

FOMassFlow = FOMassFlow(FOMassFlow ~= 0)
```

to remove the unwanted values of the particular column. How can i remove the rows of the unwanted values in the data of 732x26 ? (example, unwanted values found in column 5 row 6, i would like to remove the entire row 6 in the data of 732 rows by 26 columns)

Answer (score 0):

To remove an entire row from a matrix, so in your case it's row 6, simply do:

```
FOMassFlow(6,:) = [];
```

This will mutate `FOMassFlow` so that you have 731 rows with row 6 removed.